# Coldfusion CFDocument PDF conversion issues

Tags: pdf, coldfusion

I am trying to convert a page from HTML to PDF using CFDOCUMENT.

Here is a screen shot of the original page

[image]

and here is a screen shot of the converted PDF page:

[image]

Here is the HTML of the original page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 

                <html lang="en">

            <head>        
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
                <!--[if gt IE 8]>
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
                <![endif]-->    
                <title>Big Shots Registration</title>
                <meta name="description" content="PlayerSpace.Com offers state of the art league, tournament and sport event management tools combined with powerful social networking features." />
                <meta name="keywords" content="league management,tournament management,sports event management,league management software,tournament management software" />
                <meta name="title" content="Big Shots Registration" />      
                <meta name="author" content="PlayerSpace.Com">      
                <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 05 Nov 2013 00:00:00 E883T" />     
                <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="/favicon.ico"/>    
                <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
                <link href="/css/stylesheets.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>                
                <!--[if lt IE 8]>
                <link href="/css/ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
                <![endif]-->            
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/fullcalendar.print.css" media="print" />    
                <script type='text/javascript' src="/js/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
                <script type='text/javascript' src="/js/plugins/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js"></script>
                <script type='text/javascript' src="/js/plugins/jquery/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/jquery/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>    
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/cookie/jquery.cookies.2.2.0.min.js"></script>    
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/charts/excanvas.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/charts/jquery.flot.js"></script>    
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/charts/jquery.flot.stack.js"></script>    
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/charts/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/charts/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>    
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/sparklines/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>    
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>    
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/select2/select2.min.js"></script>    
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/uniform/uniform.js"></script>    
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/maskedinput/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js"></script>    
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/validation/languages/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/validation/jquery.validationEngine.js"" charset="utf-8"></script>    

                <script src="/js/plugins/scrollpane/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
                <script src="/js/plugins/scrollpane/mwheelIntent.js"></script>
                <script src="/js/plugins/scrollpane/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/tagsinput/jquery.tagsinput.min.js"></script>                                
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/animatedprogressbar/animated_progressbar.js"></script>    
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/qtip/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>

                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>    
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>                  
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>         
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/dataTables/FixedColumns.js"></script>         
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/bootstrap-dialog/bootstrap-dialog.js"></script>        
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/pnotify/jquery.pnotify.min.js"></script>                
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/ibutton/jquery.ibutton.min.js"></script>                    
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/scrollup/jquery.scrollUp.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/autosuggest/bsn.AutoSuggest_2.1.3.js"></script>                                 
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/autoexpand/jquery.autosize-min.js"></script>                                                    
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/stepywizard/jquery.stepy.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.js"></script>             
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/plugindetect/plugindetect.js"></script>                             

                    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>               

                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/gmap/gmap3.min.js"></script>                                
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/cookies.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/actions.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/charts.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/pwdchkr.js"></script>                                                               
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/settings.js"></script>                  
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/checkzip.js"></script>    
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/custom.js"></script>                                    
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/afterajax.js"></script>                                                 
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/aftereasytabs.js"></script>                                                                 
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/jeasyui/easyloader.js"></script>                     
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>                                                                                                                                                                                     
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plugins/easytabs/jquery.easytabs.min.js"></script>                                                                                                                              

            </head>

                    <body id="registration_body_wrap">

            <div id="registration_wizard">

                <div id="registration_body">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span12">
                            <div class="span2"></div>
                            <div class="span8">                             
                                <div class="content">
                                    <div class="workplace">

            <form method="post" action="/register/index_registration.cfm?wizard_action=pay_by_check&league=678&m0dal_update=registration_wizard&submethod=checkout&teamstatus=individual&requesttimeout=5000" name="dues_form" id="validation" class="reg_verify">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span12">
                        <h4><b class="text text-error">Registration Dues Checkout</b></h4>
                        <h5>Please review your dues payment information and complete the checkout form below. <b class="text text-error">Red text indicates a required answer.</b></h5>                 
                        <div class="alert alert-info">
                            <h4 style="margin:0px;">Main Registration</h4>
                        </div>  

                            <div class="row-form-reg clearfix">
                                <div class="pull-right tar" style="width:125px;">

                                            <input type="hidden" name="main_p_dues_division_id5" value="2381" id="main_p_dues_division_id5">

                                            <div class="input-prepend" style="margin-left:0px;">
                                                <span class="add-on">$</span>
                                                <input type="text" readonly name="sum6785" style="width:40px !important;" value="300" id="sum6785"> 
                                            </div>                                              

                                </div>      
                                <div style="width:60%;">

                                        <p style="font-size:110%;">

                                                        <b>Todd John</b> for <b class="label label-info ttRT" title="This is the selected division for this player.">BIG SHOTS Report (Non-Div 1) $300</b>                                      

                                        </p>

                        <input type="hidden" name="main_p_duesA" id="main_p_dues2141_A" value="300_2381">

                                </div>                                      
                            </div>                      
                            <div class="dr" style="margin:10px 10px 20px 10px ;"><span></span></div>                                                                                                                            

                            <div class="alert alert-info">
                                <h4 style="margin:0px;">Select your donation amount (optional)</h4>
                            </div>  

                            <div class="row-form-reg clearfix">
                                <div class="pull-right tar" style="width:125px;">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="int_donation_collected" id="int_donation_collected" value="0.00">

                                        <div class="input-prepend" style="margin-left:0px;">
                                            <span class="add-on">$</span>
                                            <input type="text" readonly name="sum_donation" value="0" id="sum_donation" style="width:40px !important;">
                                        </div>                                                                                              

                                </div>                          
                                <div style="width:60%;">

                                        <div class="pull-left tac" style="margin:0px 5px 5px 0px;">

                                                <b class="label label-warning"><h5 style="margin:2px 3px 2px 3px;">$0</h5></b>
                                                <div></div>
                                                <input type="radio" checked="checked" disabled name="donation" id="donation0.00" value="0.00" class="donation_radio" OnMouseOver="calc();" OnMouseOut="calc();">

                                        </div>      


                                </div>
                            </div>                                                  

                            <div class="alert alert-info">
                                <h4 style="margin:0px;">Pay By Check</h4>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row-form-reg clearfix">
                                <div class="span6">
                                    <label class="control-label">Total Due:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="span6 tar clearfix">
                                    <div class="input-prepend" style="margin-left:0px;">
                                        <span class="add-on">$</span></span>                                
                                        <input type="text" name="totalSum" id="totalSum" value="300" readonly onmouseover="calc();" style="width:40px !important;">
                                    </div>                                                                  
                                </div>                              
                            </div>                                                                                                                              

                            <div class="alert alert-info">
                                <h4 style="margin:0px;">Alternative Payment Arrangements</h4>
                            </div>      
                            <div class="well well-small" style="margin-top:-20px;">

                                        Please contact your director for more information on how to pay by check.

                            </div>

                    </div>
                </div>                          
            </form>                                                     
            <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">                                                               
                $(document).ready(function(){           

                        $( "#main_p_dues2141_A" ).prop( "disabled", false );

                        $( "#donation0.00" ).prop( "disabled", false );

                    $.uniform.update();
                    calc();                 

                        $("#e_m_row").hide();

                }); 
                function calc()
                {

                        elem1 = document.getElementById("sum6785");

                        elem2 = document.getElementById("sum_donation");

                    elem = document.getElementById("totalSum");                             
                    elem.value = parseFloat(elem1.value ) + parseFloat(elem2.value );
                }   
                function loadwindow()
                {
                    var myheight = $(window).height();
                    var mywidth = $(window).width();                
                    window.open(
                        'https://bigshotsdc41213.playerspace.com//register/index_registration.cfm?wizard_action=pay_by_check&league=678&teamstatus=individual&m0dal_update=registration_wizard&submethod=record_unpaid_preference&pref=check&pay_by_check=1',
                        'mywindow',
                        status=0,
                        toolbar=0,
                        menubar=0,
                        resizable=1,
                        width=mywidth,
                        scrollbars=1,
                        height=myheight
                    );
                    pay_by_checkScript();                   
                }                                           
                function pay_by_checkScript()
                {   
                    document.dues_form.target='mywindow';                                   
                    document.dues_form.action='http://bigshotsdc41213.playerspace.com/register/index_registration.cfm?wizard_action=pay_by_check&league=678&teamstatus=individual&m0dal_update=registration_wizard&submethod=record_unpaid_preference&pref=check&pay_by_check=1';
                    document.dues_form.str_billing_fname.value='pay_by_check';
                    document.dues_form.str_billing_lname.value='pay_by_check';
                    document.dues_form.str_billing_address1.value='pay_by_check';
                    document.dues_form.city.value='pay_by_check';
                    document.dues_form.str_billing_phone.value='555-555-5555';
                    document.dues_form.str_credit_card_type.value='pay_by_check';
                    document.dues_form.str_credit_card_number.value='4828640590401142';
                    document.dues_form.str_ccv_number.value='pay_by_check'  ;                                                                                                           
                    document.dues_form.submit();
                    //window.location = "http://bigshotsdc41213.playerspace.com/register/index_registration.cfm?wizard_action=registration_complete&league=678&teamstatus=individual&m0dal_update=registration_wizard&submethod=record_unpaid_preference&pref=check"
                }
                $(document).on("click", "[id*=uniform-donation]", function(){    
                    var myval =  $(this).find(':radio').val();
                    $('#int_donation_collected').val(myval);
                    $('#sum_donation').val(myval);                                              
                    $(this).find(':radio').prop('checked', true);
                    $.uniform.update();
                    calc();   
                });     
                $(document).on("click", ".iagree", function(){    
                    $(this).addClass("iagreewidth");
                    $(this).val('');
                    $(this).attr("placeholder", "");
                    calc();   
                });                                     
                function showem()   
                {                                               
                    $("#e_m_row").show();
                    if($("#confirmmultiple").length > 0){
                        $("#confirmmultiple").show();                   
                    }      
                    $("#checkout_now").attr('value','SUBMIT FIRST INSTALLMENT PAYMENT >>');                                                 
                    calc();                             
                }
                function hideem()   
                {           
                    $(".iagree").removeClass("iagreewidth");
                    $(".iagree").val('');
                    $(".iagree").attr('placeholder', 'Type "I AGREE" in this box to complete your order and click the "PAY THESE DUES" button.');               
                    $("#checkout_now").attr('value','SUBMIT DUES PAYMENT >>');                                              
                    calc();                                                 
                    $("#e_m_row").hide();
                    if($("#confirmmultiple").length > 0){
                        $("#confirmmultiple").hide();                   
                    }                           
                }                                                       
            </script>   
            <script>    
                window.onload = function() {
                    for(var i = 0, l = document.getElementsByTagName('input').length; i < l; i++) {
                        if(document.getElementsByTagName('input').item(i).type == 'text') {
                            document.getElementsByTagName('input').item(i).setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off');
                        };
                    };
                };                                          
            </script>                                                                                                               
            <script type="text/javascript">  
                function disableEnterKey(e){  
                var key; 
                    if(window.event){ 
                    key = window.event.keyCode; 
                    } else { 
                    key = e.which;      
                    } 
                    if(key == 13){ 
                    return false; 
                    } else { 
                    return true; 
                    }       
                } 
            </script>                       

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="span2"></div>                           
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

                    </body>
                </html>
```

I can't seem to get the pdf output to match the original. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: wow, that is a lot of javascript plugins!

Comment: yeah i know. I'm probably just going to comment them out when the pdf is created.

Comment: I ended up just removing the unnecessary styling and went back to basics. Tables and header tags with limited formatting. I guess it will have to make do for now.

Comment: It look like the CSS didn't make it

Comment: It did, unfortunately there's many things CFDOCUMENT doesn't support, like gradient backgrounds and bootstrap classes.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience PDF rendering was actually easier than I expected. What I would do is create a CFM file that just outputs the core page structure you want - so lose all of those javascript files and everything and just have the regular markup that you need on it. A normal CSS sheet should work just fine, but you might need to use CFINCLUDE to include it inline rather than relying on a link meta tag in your header.

The code to create your PDF is then as follows:

```
<cfdocument format="pdf" 
    pagetype="custom" 
    unit="cm" 
    pagewidth="21" 
    pageheight="29.7" 
    margintop="0" 
    marginbottom="0" 
    marginleft="0" 
    marginright="0" 
    filename="#pdf.path_render_page#" 
    overwrite="true"
    fontembed="yes"
>
    <cfinclude template='render_page.cfm'>
</cfdocument>
```

So the basic output CFM file is CFINCLUDE'd inside your CFDOCUMENT tag, makes for nice compact code and is easy to separate the PDF creation from the template. Your CFM template then would have your CSS file CFINCLUDE'd inside that too. The recursive include should work fine.

If you're wanting this to be printed out on paper then it gets a bit tricky, as you start having to work in physical measurements and not pixels, so your layout will end up being a lot of trial and error - printing one out and seeing how it looks etc.

The big gotcha is with fonts. If you want a font to be embedded in your PDF then it needs to be installed on the server machine, and referenced properly. If you open the CF admin you can view a page that lists the fonts available, and it has a few columns with different references to each font. I'm never sure which one of those columns gives the right reference for your CSS to marry up with the right font - I think it might vary depending on the font and the platform your server is running on, one of them will be right though, so again just trial and error.

Looking at your document it seems to be a form, so not sure quite how that would make sense in a straight PDF version - you'd might want to amend the layout anyway to make it more like a physical form perhaps?